# Input and text at the right

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have a problem with my last input, there is a text at the right `123458`.

[image]

My text is too far to the right how can I move it to the left in bootstrap 5?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="home-content container ">
    <h1 class="text-center pt-5 pb-3">Sélection d'un portefeuille </h1>
    <form>
        <div class="row row-cols-3 pt-3">
            <div class="col text-end">
                <label for="nameVariable" class="form-label">Nom du Titulaire</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nameVariable" style="min-width: 380px" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-cols-3 pt-3">
            <div class="col text-end">
                <label for="nameVariable" class="form-label">Intitulé</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nameVariable" style="min-width: 380px" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-cols-3 pt-3">
            <div class="col">
            </div>
            <div class="col text-start">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Rechercher</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      
       <div class="row row-cols-3 pt-3">
      <div class="col text-end">
        <label for="nameVariable" class="form-label"
          >Numero d'identification</label
        >
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          name="nameVariable"
          style="max-width: 190px"
          aria-describedby="emailHelp"
          required
        />
      </div>
      (Ex:123458)
    </div>
    <div class="row row-cols-3 pt-3">
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col text-start">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Rechercher</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've tagged the question Bootstrap 5, yet the code sample is using Bootstrap 4.

To align the text, put it inside the `col-4`, and make the form-control, `d-inline` which will make it `display:inline` and all the text to flow to the right of the input.

```
<div class="home-content container ">
    <h1 class="text-center pt-5 pb-3">Sélection d'un portefeuille </h1>
    <form>
        <div class="row row-cols-3 pt-3">
            <div class="col text-end">
                <label for="nameVariable" class="form-label">Nom du Titulaire</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nameVariable" style="min-width: 380px" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-cols-3 pt-3">
            <div class="col text-end">
                <label for="nameVariable" class="form-label">Intitulé</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nameVariable" style="min-width: 380px" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-cols-3 pt-3">
            <div class="col">
            </div>
            <div class="col text-start">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Rechercher</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-cols-3 pt-3">
            <div class="col text-end">
                <label for="nameVariable" class="form-label">Numero d'identification</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control d-inline" name="nameVariable" style="max-width: 190px" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required />
                (Ex:123458)
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="row row-cols-3 pt-3">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col text-start">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Rechercher</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/k84E4fVz1y